# Hyperlinks within email body work in browser but not Gmail mobile app

Tags: html, gmail

I've got a program that generates email reports and sends to certain recipients. The email contains a table of contents with hyperlinks to bookmarks later in the email.

This works perfectly when viewing mails in the browser, e.g. on gmail.com. However, recently something seems to have changed in the Gmail mobile app, and my hyperlinks no longer work there.

When generating the email, the link is of the form:

```
<a href="section_1">Section 1</a>
```

and the bookmark is of the form:

```
<a name="section_1"/>
```

In the browser, the link URL appears in the form:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#m_3653008429050877336_1
```

In the Gmail app, however, the link appears in the form:

```
x-thread://-90370221/435827759917983#m_3653008429050877336_1
```

Any ideas what has changed, and how to make my intra-document hyperlinks work again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **Orignal Answer**

This functionality is not available in gmail app. Here is the link to google forum where you can confirm:

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/CdhA_3Z1yTo

You can insert link in the gmail app (like http://www.google.com) in Gmail app which is automatically converted to clickable link when you send the message but if you want hyperlink (like "click here" and when you click on it you are directed to the link to the page) you will have to do it from your browser only. There is no option available in Gmail app to do that.

The alternate solution is to use Microsoft Outlook. Add your google account in Outlook app.

In the compose section long press in the area then you get option to add hyperlink.

## **Answer after discussion in chat**

It seems that the problem is with the gmail app version. If you want to open  links received in your gmail app so that you are redirected to the location of message in the same mail you need to have minimum version 8 of gmail app. Verified this as I was able to access the links in my gmail app as well as my browser.

Platforms on which veried the links:

Android 6.0.1 - Gmail Version: 8.1.7.182107449.release

Windows 10 - Chrome: Version 63.0.3239.132

Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) - Firefox: Version 57.0.4

Comment: Arg. That's really not what I wanted to hear. Funny thing is, it _used_ to work. Then something changed and it stopped working...

Comment: if the question is answered, can you mark it as answered :)

Comment: I know; I'm waiting to see if anyone else can present any kind of hack/workaround :-)

Comment: I just added an alternate fot your problem which will resolve your problem

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not in control of the clients. I've got about 10,000 subscribers getting these emails and I can't tell them what client to use.

Comment: Oh wait, I think there's a misunderstanding here. I know how to create the hyperlinks. That's not a problem. It's the fact that the hyperlinks in the Gmail app do not work, whereas the same links in the same email do work when viewed in the browser.

Comment: that is what i have mentioned

Comment: did you read my answer completely including the part where i mentioned you can insert a link but not hyperlink in the gmail app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163571/discussion-between-shaul-behr-and-dadybyte).

Answer (score 2):

To get around the Gmail app not having an option to insert a link into text (hyperlink) on my mobile device I use another mobile app to compose the email first. Currently, the only app I have discovered to be compatible with this trick is Google Docs. I find it works for typing, formatting, inserting images and creating hyperlinks.

To upload from Google Docs into Gmail I am presently only aware of the ability to highlight the planned body of the email in Google Docs then pasting it into Gmail.

Using Google Docs I am aware of the ability to carry over changes to some features of the hypertext. Such as colour, boldness, italics, size, underline. There are possibly more customizable options available before inserting what you have composed into Gmail.

I am unaware of any tricks to create a usable hyperlink of images for use in the Gmail app.

Such a feature outside the “Signature” on Gmail desktop could prove most beneficial.

Comment: This is legendary. I work for Google and had no idea this was a thing, thanks! I've discovered the text styling doesn't always line up between the two editors, but using the "remove formatting" button in Gmail keeps the link & strips it back to plain style.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was adding hyperlinks as following

```
<a href="//mywebsite.com">Click Here</a>
```

I did it to handle the possibility of https not available on the website as links are dynamic in the email. When I changed it to following then it worked on gmail app as well.

```
<a href="https://mywebsite.com">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it in the gmail mobile app. Sorry. Also, it matters what version you have.

Answer (score -1):

I found a link on these forums with a fix. Essentially they said that if you put a span inside the  link, it will fix the problem. I've not yet had a chance to test it however. According to the post:

This won't work:

```
<a href="#foo">Bar</a>
```

But either of the following will:

```
<a href="#foo"><span>Bar</span></a>
<a href="#foo"><font>Bar</font></a>
```

Comment: Looks interesting, will give it a try! Meanwhile please can you include a link to the original post you're referring to?

Comment: Alas, no joy. I added the span tags but the hyperlinks still don't work

Comment: tried both span and font tags, but anchors still doesn't work on gmail mobile app